# Removing Facebook contact field from user contact not working

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm trying to unset the Facebook link for users who registered in the past 365 days. For users who have completed more than a year, don't unset.

Here's my code which is not working:

```
function modify_user_contact_methods( $user_contact ) {

    get_currentuserinfo(); 
        $user_data = get_userdata($user_ID);
        $registered_date = $user_data->user_registered;
        if (strtotime($registered_date) > strtotime('-365 days')){
             // Remove user contact methods
         unset( $user_contact['facebook']    );
        }

    return $user_contact;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'modify_user_contact_methods' );
```

It shows the field. If I remove the condition, it unsets for every user. So the set/unset is correct, only the 365 condition is wrong, I guess. But it seems correct, what amI doing wrong? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct .

Have u checked $registered_date ?  maybe its format is wrong .

Comment: How do i check?

Comment: Cause i think your code is correct ,so i guess the format of $registered_date maybe  wrong ,var_dump it for check.